# UILabel does not wrap on initial load within TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitableview

I am creating a chat based app, which uses a `UITableView` to hold all the messages within a conversation. To create a chat bubble, I have a wrapper view (wrapView) which is constrained to the top, bottom, right, and left of the TableViewCell. As a subview I have a `UILabel` which holds the message which was sent. I used `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for the `UILabel` to ensure the text within the label won't go beyond the parent View. The number of lines for the `UILabel` is also set to 0. I set the following parameters within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
// Get the cell
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LeftBubbleText") as! LeftTextTableViewCell

// Set the message
cell.messageLabel.text = message

// Set the message label's max width
cell.messageLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.wrapView.frame.width - 16
```

When the conversation first loads, the text within the `UILabel` is not wrapped properly. It is truncated at the end of the wrapper view. But when the cell is scrolled off screen and then re-appears, the text is wrapped just fine after the cell is reused.

How can I ensure the text within the UILabel is wrapped properly on the initial load and not just when the cell is reused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely to be that the frame width you are using is wrong. Cells created using `deqeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` have no size class associated with them because they have no parent view. Hence if you have constraints in your cell, trying to calculate layout sizes manually does not work properly.

You should be using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` to dequeue your cells

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I didn't realize using `deqeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ` cause no size class to be associated with the cell. I also added `cell.wrapView.frame = CGRect(x: cell.wrapView.frame.origin.x, y: cell.wrapView.frame.origin.y, width: enoteThreadTableView.frame.width - 96, height: 36) ` right after the dequeue call which solved my initial problem. Since the wrapper view is constrained to both the left (50) and the right (46) of the cell, that made the view size properly on the first load.